# In .NET, Array only extends IEnumerable, so will there be boxing and unboxing when a foreach loop goes through a value type array?

Tags: .net, arrays, generics, foreach, value-type

Array only extends the non-generic version of IEnumerable, so will there be boxing and unboxing when a foreach loop goes through a value type array?

I am guessing not, because that would be lame.
If my guess is right, then how does foreach go through a value type array? Does it not use the Array.GetEnumerator method? And if not, why does Array extends IEnumerable?

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`Array` has a lot of special casing in the runtime. In particular it is pseudo-generic. i.e. if you specify a concrete array type like `T[]` implement the generic collection interfaces like `IEnumerable<T>`.

If I recall correctly it even supported non boxing iteration with `foreach` before generics by having `GetEnumerator` return a concrete type with a strongly typed `Current`. This works since `foreach` does not require the `IEnumerator`/`IEnumerable` interfaces, but works with correctly named members too.

So you can iterate over arrays with `foreach` without boxing.

Comment: Thanks.  why does Array extends IEnumerable if it is not used?

Comment: It is used, byt it is special-cased in a lot of code, like foreach-loops, where the compiler notices that you're giving it an array. However, if you're in a method that takes an IEnumerable, it won't know that, and then it is required.

Comment: The special handling is not in the runtime; it's in the C# compiler, which translates the foreach loop into a for loop.

Comment: @phoog Using the `for` loop is a special case of the compiler, implementing `IList<T>` as if it were generic is a special case in the runtime.

Answer (score 5):

CodesInChaos's answer is incorrect.  A value-type array is iterated without boxing because of special handling in the C# compiler, not special handling in the runtime.  The C# compiler translates a foreach loop into a for loop when the static type of the iterated collection is an array type.

Also, your question is based on an incorrect assumption ("Array only extends the non-generic version of IEnumerable").  In fact, arrays implement the generic `IEnumerable<T>`; it's just that this is done using explicit member implementation, for reasons of backward compatibility.  (Also, the fact that arrays implement the generic interfaces *is* a case of special handling in the runtime; you will not see them in the definition of `System.Array` when you decompile mscorlib.)

This means that if you have an array `int[] a`, and you call `a.GetEnumerator()`, you'll get a non-generic `IEnumerator` reference.  However, you can explicitly cast to get a generic `IEnumerator<int>` reference: `((IEnumerable<int>)a).GetEnumerator()`.

Comment: Can confirm - I just tried this out in Linqpad 6 (for .NET Core 3) used `foreach` with an `Int32[] arr` and the generated IL was the same as a `for( Int32 i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++ )` - obviously this only works when the compiler knows the loop subject is an array - if I downcast it to `IEnumerable<Int32>` then it gives me the `GetEnumerable()` version (though it does return a generic `IEnumerator<Int32>` instead of a non-generic `IEnumerator`).