# Testing foreach box/unbox on a regular array?

Tags: c#, .net, arrays, foreach, boxing

I've read [this excellent question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5674388/in-net-array-only-extends-ienumerable-so-will-there-be-boxing-and-unboxing-wh) about how a regular `int[]` is handled under `foreach` ( box or not) loop.

`Array` does implement the non-generic `IEnumerable` so it has to use an`object` inside ( and not `int`)

But it [turns out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5674439/859154) that  - in run-time it actually handled as `IEnumerable<T>`

How can I test/proof (that there isn't boxing )it by a simple `C#` code? ( *and not by reading IL.*)

Comment: Actually, the C# compiler translates `foreach` to `for` for arrays.

Comment: Why do you say "and not by reading IL"? Seeing what the compiler actually spits out seems to be the only sensible option here...

Comment: @JonSkeet if it is the only solution...so ok.

Comment: If you read "The `foreach` statement" in [the C# Language Specification](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228593.aspx) you wil see that arrays are handled as a kind of special case. Quote: If the type `X` of _expression_ is an array type [...] the **element type** is the element type of the array type `X`. [end quote] Note, if it's a multi-dimensional array, like `int[,]` or `int[,,]`, you can still `foreach` through it without boxing. Jon Skeet verified that (inspecting the IL) just the other day (see the **comments** to [his answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14030150/1336654)).

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen Your comment(and Jon's answer) was the trigger to my question . however Jon wrote about `GetLowerBound` and `GetUpperBound ` but I didn't know  how how it is related to boxing or not boxing.

Comment: I don't think the interfaces are really relevant when you use `foreach` with array types because array types have always been handled in a special way (since before generics were introduced in .NET and C#).

Comment: @RoyiNamir That means that the code gets the height and width of the rectangular array in order to index the elements directly. Like phoog commented above, it's really a `for` loop (one `for` loop for each dimension in the array).

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen Isn't the answer below is a valid proof ? the `getType` returns int.

Comment: @phoog Do you know it from CLS specification or from `IL` ?

Comment: @RoyiNamir the C# compiler is not controlled by the CLS specification.  I do not know whether the C# specification explicitly calls for foreach loops to be translated to for loops, so this may be an implementation detail.  I know that it translates to a for loop because I've read something that Eric Lippert wrote (don't remember exactly what) and because I looked at some IL before I wrote my answer to this question.

Comment: @RoyiNamir the fact that GetType returns `typeof(int)` does not prove that there's no boxing.

Comment: @phoog _Actually, the C# compiler translates foreach to for for arrays_....So foreach never do boxing ?

Comment: @RoyiNamir it's certainly possible for foreach to box: `int[] ints = {1, 2, 3}; foreach (object i in ints);`  In other words, you can force boxing by specifying a reference type.  You can also force boxing by using the array through a (non-generic) IEnumerable reference; the compiler can't do the special handling of an array when the static type of the expression is not an array type.  Example: `void WriteAll(IEnumerable e) { foreach (var element in e) Console.WriteLine(element); } void CallIt() { WriteAll(new int[] {1, 2, 3}); }`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your question assumes incorrectly (as does the question you link to) that arrays do not implement the generic `IEnumerable<T>`.  They do.  You can see this using reflection:

```
var array = new int[0];
var enumerator = array.GetEnumerator();
var enumeratorType = enumerator.GetType();
var propertyInfo = enumeratorType.GetProperty("Current");
var propertyType = propertyInfo.PropertyType;
Console.WriteLine(propertyType.Name); //prints "Object";
var otherEnumerator = ((IEnumerable<int>)array).GetEnumerator();
enumeratorType = otherEnumerator.GetType();
propertyInfo = enumeratorType.GetProperty("Current");
propertyType = propertyInfo.PropertyType;
Console.WriteLine(propertyType.Name); //prints "Int32";
```

However, if you write a foreach loop on a statically-typed array reference, the C# compiler translates it to a for loop.  I don't think there's any way to check that without looking at the IL.

From http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.aspx:

Important

Starting with the .NET Framework 2.0, the Array class implements the `System.Collections.Generic.IList<T>`, `System.Collections.Generic.ICollection<T>`, and `System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<T>` generic interfaces. The implementations are provided to arrays at run time, and therefore are not visible to the documentation build tools. As a result, the generic interfaces do not appear in the declaration syntax for the Array class, and there are no reference topics for interface members that are accessible only by casting an array to the generic interface type (explicit interface implementations). The key thing to be aware of when you cast an array to one of these interfaces is that members which add, insert, or remove elements throw NotSupportedException.

Comment: @RoyiNamir see the quote from MSDN that I just added to the answer.

Comment: ohhhh sh*****t  ! indeed important.  Thank you for the info ! p.s. how did they swing that ? applying `Ienumerable<T>....` at runtime ....? this makes me wonder , whether this whole runtime applying thing is impacting performance...

Comment: @RoyiNamir perhaps it does impact performance, but I doubt it's a significant impact.  I imagine the implementation is added once per array type, not for each array instance.

Comment: How in runtime did they do that ? ( stating : "from now on , you Implemenet Ienumerable<T>...")

Comment: @RoyiNamir because each type is loaded into memory once (per AppDomain, I believe).  Type members are defined by the type's in-memory representation, which does not change once it's loaded.  The in-memory representation of each object contains a pointer into the in-memory representation of its type.

Answer (score 5):

I like @phoog's answer, so just for fun :)

**Helper class**

```
public static class ILUtils
{
    private static Dictionary<short, OpCode> s_opcodes = new Dictionary<short, OpCode>();

    static ILUtils()
    {
        FieldInfo[] opCodeFields = typeof(OpCodes).GetFields(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static);
        foreach (FieldInfo opCodeField in opCodeFields)
        {
            if (opCodeField.FieldType != typeof(OpCode))
                continue;

            OpCode opcode = (OpCode)opCodeField.GetValue(null);
            s_opcodes.Add(opcode.Value, opcode);
        }
    }

    public static bool ContainsOpcodes(MethodInfo methodInfo, IEnumerable<OpCode> targetOpCodes)
    {
        MethodBody methodBody = methodInfo.GetMethodBody();

        using (BinaryReader ilReader = new BinaryReader(new MemoryStream(methodBody.GetILAsByteArray())))
        {
            while (ilReader.BaseStream.Position < ilReader.BaseStream.Length)
            {
                short opCodeValue = ilReader.ReadByte();
                if (opCodeValue == 0xfe)
                    opCodeValue = (short)(opCodeValue << 8 | ilReader.ReadByte());

                OpCode opCode = s_opcodes[opCodeValue];
                if (targetOpCodes.Contains(opCode))
                    return true;

                int argumentSize = 4;
                if (opCode.OperandType == OperandType.InlineNone)
                    argumentSize = 0;
                else if (opCode.OperandType == OperandType.ShortInlineBrTarget || opCode.OperandType == OperandType.ShortInlineI || opCode.OperandType == OperandType.ShortInlineVar)
                    argumentSize = 1;
                else if (opCode.OperandType == OperandType.InlineVar)
                    argumentSize = 2;
                else if (opCode.OperandType == OperandType.InlineI8 || opCode.OperandType == OperandType.InlineR)
                    argumentSize = 8;
                else if (opCode.OperandType == OperandType.InlineSwitch)
                {
                    int num = ilReader.ReadInt32();
                    argumentSize = (int)(4 * num + 4);
                }

                ilReader.BaseStream.Position += argumentSize;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

**Example usage**

```
private static void BoxingForEach()
{
    IEnumerable foo = (IEnumerable)new int[10];
    foreach (int i in foo) ;
}

private static void NoBoxingForEach()
{
    int[] foo = new int[10];
    foreach (int i in foo) ;
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    MethodInfo boxingForEach = typeof(Program).GetMethod("BoxingForEach", BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
    MethodInfo noBoxingForEach = typeof(Program).GetMethod("NoBoxingForEach", BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.NonPublic);

    Console.WriteLine("BoxingForEach is using boxing: {0}", 
        ILUtils.ContainsOpcodes(boxingForEach, new[] { OpCodes.Box, OpCodes.Unbox, OpCodes.Unbox_Any }));

    Console.WriteLine("NoBoxingForEach is using boxing: {0}", 
        ILUtils.ContainsOpcodes(noBoxingForEach, new[] { OpCodes.Box, OpCodes.Unbox, OpCodes.Unbox_Any }));
}
```

**Results**

> > BoxingForEach is using boxing: True
> >
> > NoBoxingForEach is using boxing: False

Comment: This is one of the most humorous answers I've seen for a long time. Proof without "reading IL"!

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to verify if boxing is going on behind the scenes without look at the emitted IL.

But try this:

```
static void Main()
{
  int[] arr1 = { 7, 9, 13, };
  Array arr2 = arr1;
  IEnumerable arr3 = arr1;  // non-generic IEnumerable

  foreach (var x in arr1)  // hold mouse over var keyword to see compile-time type
  {
    Overloaded(x);  // go to definition to see which overload is used
  }
  foreach (var x in arr2)  // hold mouse over var keyword to see compile-time type
  {
    Overloaded(x);  // go to definition to see which overload is used
  }
  foreach (var x in arr3)  // hold mouse over var keyword to see compile-time type
  {
    Overloaded(x);  // go to definition to see which overload is used
  }
}

static void Overloaded(int x)
{
  Console.WriteLine("int!");
}
static void Overloaded(object x)
{
  Console.WriteLine("object!");
}
```

It's easy to see that boxing does take place with `arr2` and `arr3`. Technically, we can't be sure if boxing happens with `arr1` (would have to check the IL), but we can see that the implicitly typed (`var`) variable becomes an `int` variable, and that's kind of a clue.

Answer (score -1):

Is something like this satisfying?

```
        int[] foo = new int[10];

        foreach (object o in foo)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(o.GetType());
            int? bar = o as int?;
            Console.WriteLine(bar);
        }
        Console.ReadKey();
```

It is hard to be sure without checking IL for implicit casts.

Comment: This _certainly_ has boxing since you put the `int` into a variable `o` of compile-time type `object`!

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen not to mention that calling `GetType()` causes the runtime to box the int, so even if it were `foreach (int i in foo)`, you'd still have boxing.

Comment: Wasn't aware that GetType() caused boxing at runtime. Can't think of a better method though. Would be happy to see something really relevent.

Comment: @phoog you mean `calling GetType() causes the runtime to un-box`...cause it was under `o` but `gettype` returned `int`

Comment: @RoyiNamir, no, I don't mean that.  Try this: `Console.WriteLine(1.GetType());`.  This compiles to IL meaning: load 1; box; call object.GetType.  You can only call GetType on a reference to an object, so if you want to call it on an instance of a value type, the compiler has to box it first.

Comment: I'm glad I was mistaken (and was corrected)  , like , Lukior  , I didn't know it also.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen You say "_This certainly has boxing since you put the int into a variable o of compile-time type object!_" but I read that foeach is translated to `for` loop (when dealing with arrays). so it does not do boxing. can you please elaborate ?

Comment: @RoyiNamir An `int` is a value of a value type. It cannot be in a reference type variable without being boxed. It may be true that `foreach` is translated to a `for`. If you say `foreach (int i in foo) { ... }`, it may be translated to `for (int index = 0; index < foo.Length; index++) { int i = foo[index]; ... }` and then no boxing occurs. But when you say `foreach (object o in foo) { ... }`, even if it's translated to a `for`, you get boxing: `for (int index = 0; index < foo.Length; index++) { object o = /* boxes */ foo[index]; ... }`.

Comment: Regarding `GetType()`: If you have a value that's already boxed, like `object o = 1;`, then calling `o.GetType();` reuses the same box. If you have a value type variable, like `int i = 1;`, then `i.GetType();` needs to box the variable first before it can call the non-virtual instance method defined by `System.Object`. With nullable value types, magical boxing occurs. Try this, and you will understand: `int? n = null; n.ToString() /* OK, no boxing */ ; n.GetType() /* Bang! */ ;`.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen so whats all this stuff that in runtime array implements Ienumerable<T> ? can you please explain ?

Comment: @RoyiNamir Since .NET 1, the [class `System.Array`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.aspx) is non-generic and implements the non-generic `IList` interface and therefore also the non-generic `IEnumerable`. So any array is a non-generic `IList` (indexing via the interface throws if the array is multi-dimensional) and non-generic `IEnumerable` (hence you can use LINQ methods `.Cast` and `.OfType` on `System.Array`). Since .NET 2 (generics), a _single-dimensional_ array `T[]` is also `IList<T>` and therefore `IEnumerable<T>`. So you can use LINQ on a single-dimensional array.